namespace map : Keep the main namespace
Related to this question, in a comment he advised me to use -map instead of -command.
I'm trying to apply it but I've encountered a problem: I want to keep my main namespace ns1 like this :
namespace eval ns1 {
    namespace eval ::ns2 {
        namespace ensemble create -map {
            test ::ns1::name
        }
    }
}
# Call proc 
ns2 test

This works, but related to my last question , this is equivalent to writing like this:
namespace eval ns1 {}
namespace eval ns2 {
    namespace ensemble create -map {
        test ::ns1::name
    }
}

My apprehension is that ::ns2 exists in another package or file, that's why I'd like to keep ns1 as the main namespace and make ns2 a child of ns1. So I can call my test command like this: ns2 test and not ns1::ns2 test

The comment advised to use -map instead of -subcommands. For what you want, using -command is completely appropriate. However, if you are afraid that another package may use ns2, then it is also conceivable that it implements a ns2 command.

If you want ns2 to be a child of ns1 your first example needs namespace eval ns2 ... (without the leading ::). Or use ::ns1::ns2 for the fully qualified name.

@Shawn, ok but I don't want ::ns1::ns2 test but only ns2 test but keep ns2 as child of ns1 I don't know if my question is clear, but I don't have the impression that it's not possible. Can you confirm ?

For your own code, use whatever you wish. The restriction to use -map is a feature of Tcl's own ensembles for commands like string and info, and is to allow the bytecode compiler to reach inside without needing complex multi-stage command resolution (that code is complex enough as it is, thank you!). That isn't a feature you have open in your ensembles (you aren't writing bytecode compiler plugins) so you also don't have the restrictions that go with it.
In default mode, ensembles use the exported commands of the namespace. That involves a dynamic search. If you give -subcommands or -map, you skip that search. The -subcommands option lets you directly provide the result of the search (used for subcommand matching and error message generation) and -map also let's you set exactly how to look up the implementation of each subcommand instead of leaving it implicitly the command in the namespace.
You never need -command; you could just rename the command after creation instead. The -command option just let's you skip doing that and make the ensemble with the given name directly. Ensembles remember their initial namespace (unlike procedures).
In short, you don't need any option at all when making an ensemble, but using either -subcommands or -map to have a defined API might be a good idea anyway. Like that, you won't get accidental implementation pieces showing up.

Files and namespaces have nothing at all to do with each other in Tcl. That's just how you choose to organise things, not a language internal model thing.

I want use -map but using two namespaces one as child of other, but thanks anyway for the explanations.
